# Why Methods in Lambda Expressions?

Tags: c#, methods, lambda

In C# 6.0, Microsoft introduced the ability to write methods in the form of lambda expressions (really, it's somewhere between a function block and a pure lambda expression; I am not sure if it's even truly a lambda expression). Normally, this is how I would write my methods:

```
private static int Add(int x, int y) { 
    return x + y; 
}
```

However, as of C# 6.0, the same method can be rewritten as so:

```
private static int Add(int x, int y) => x + y;
```

What I don't understand is, why would I use the latter in favor of the former? Is it purely stylish or are there situations where doing away with function blocks is actually beneficial? And in terms of readability, to me, the second form looks a bit unusual. I can relate better to the first one.

Comment: AFAIK, in your given example above, it is stylish

Comment: For a simple method like the Add above, i might use it just to avoid typing all the braces and creating a whole function block for a simple function. For anything more complex, id use a normal function block. That send, i think this is somewhat subjective.

Comment: Please, read MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [C# : The New and Improved C# 6.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/magazine/dn802602.aspx):

> There’s nothing particularly radical about expression bodied functions. As with most of the features found in C# 6.0, they’re intended to provide a simplified syntax for cases where the implementation is simple.

Comment: So it's basically stylish.

Answer (score 0):

I was surprised, but the lambda definition actually results in less IL then the original.

Original:

```
// Method begins at RVA 0x2074
// Code size 9 (0x9)
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    [0] int32
)

IL_0000: nop
IL_0001: ldarg.0
IL_0002: ldarg.1
IL_0003: add
IL_0004: stloc.0
IL_0005: br.s IL_0007

IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ret
```

Lambda:

```
// Method begins at RVA 0x2089
// Code size 4 (0x4)
.maxstack 8

IL_0000: ldarg.0
IL_0001: ldarg.1
IL_0002: add
IL_0003: ret
```

So there could be some minor performance benefit.  However, it appears that this might be only when building without optimizations or for the debugger; see the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26323373/why-is-the-br-s-il-opcode-used-in-this-case) for more details about that.  So after optimizations, the answer is probably just a style choice.

Comment: To be clear, is there one single mode that results in both of those IL bodies for the two different implementations, or did you switch between debug and release during your testing?

Comment: @hvd I did switch between debug and release, and they ended up with the same IL.  Also, Optimize code in build options for the project remained checked throughout, so the optimizations that the other answer talks about may be from another optimizer or from the JIT that runs the IL code.  Interestingly, ILSpy gives the same non-lamda code for the C# decompile.